# MySQL issue with CREATE TABLE film database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table with multiple foreign keys which reference other parent tables. 1 of my foreign keys is being accepted 'fk_film_id' however the second is not due to a syntax error. how can I get this to pass?

the body of my tables is below:

```
create table `Actor_Role` (
`Actor_Role_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Actor_Role` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Character_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Alias_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Actor_Role_id`)
 );

create table `Actor` (
`Actor_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`First_Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Date_of_Birth` DATE NOT NULL,
`Nationality` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Gender` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`Residence` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Actor_id`)
);

create table `Film` (
`Film_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Release_Date` DATE NOT NULL,
`Running_Time` INT NOT NULL,
`Budget` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`Box_Office` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`Rating` INT NOT NULL,
`Language` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Film_id`)
);

create table `Film_Staff` (
`Staff_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`First_Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Nationality` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Staff_id`)
);

create table `Staff_Role` (
`Staff_Role_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Staff_Role` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Staff_Role_id`)
);

create table `Infinity_Stones` (
`Stone_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Colour` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`Power` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Stone_id`)
);
```

The table I am trying to make looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Film_Staff_Role(
    -> `Film_id` INT NOT NULL,
    -> `Role_id` INT NOT NULL,
    -> `Staff_id` INT NOT NULL,
    -> FOREIGN KEY fk_film_id(Film_id)
    ->  REFERENCES film(Film_id)
    -> ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ->  FOREIGN KEY fk_Role_id(Role_id)
    -> REFERENCES Staff_Role(Staff_Role_id)
    -> ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ->  FOREIGN KEY fk_Staff_id(Staff_id)
    -> REFERENCES Film_Staff(Staff_id)
    -> ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ON DELETE RESTRICT
    -> )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

However I receive the following issue when I attempt to execute:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY fk_Staff_Role_id(Staff_Role_id) 
>   REFERENCES Staff_Role(Staff_Role_id' at line 9

How can this be overcome?

Comment: You're missing a `,` after the previous foreign key definition.

Comment: Consider using `VARCHAR(255)` as a default general-purpose string-type field and only override this if you have a compelling reason. Many MySQL installations will silently truncate any data which doesn’t fit, resulting in lost data, user complaints, and other serious issues. Names and email addresses are quite frequently surprisingly long, so accommodating these is important.